# Method undefined for type method?

Tags: java, methods

I have a program to find pythagorean triples. in it, i have an object that needs to be used to call methods. Said object is broken. Errors are "    The method Triples(int) is undefined for the type Triples" and "The method `greatesCommonFactor()` is undefined for the type Triples" mind you, not everything in Triples does useful stuff atm. It isn't completely finished yet.

```
public class TriplesRunner
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       int number;
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter the natural number :: ");
       number=keyboard.nextInt();

       Triples test = new Triples();
       test.Triples(number);
       test.greatestCommonFactor(number);
       System.out.println(test.toString());
   }
}



public class Triples
{
   public int number;


    public Triples(int num)
    {
        setNum(number);
    }

    public void setNum(int num)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
    }

    public int greatestCommonFactor(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int max = 0;
        for(a=1; a<=number-2; a++)
        {
            for(b=a+1; b<=number-1; b++)
            {
                for(c=b+1; c<=number; c++)
                {
                    if(a*a + b*b == c*c);
                    }
                }
            }
        return 1;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String output="";
        output+="a + b + c";
        return output+"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a method named `Triples` in your `Triples` class.

Comment: You're confusing constructor with methods. They're not the same.

Comment: Your semi-pasted error has a spelling mistake: _greates_. The code doesn't seem to have this mistake, but that's why you don't paraphrase errors.

Comment: `public Triples (...)` is a constructor, not a method. And `public void Triples (...)` will not compile

Comment: You're calling the constructor with `Triples test = new Triples();` and then calling `test.Triples(number)` which is a method.  Do `Triples test = new Triples(number);` to invoke the constructor you've created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to call the constructor as a method,

Change this part:

```
Triples test = new Triples();
test.Triples(number);
```

to

```
Triples.test = new Triples(number);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Triples` isn't a method - it's your constructor, meaning it's invoked with the `new` operator:

```
Triples test = new Triples(number);
```

`greatestCommonFactor` is not defined properly. It currently takes three `int` arguments, instead of taking none and using `Triples`' data members:

```
public int greatestCommonFactor()
```

Comment: You typo'd Triple just before the end, and `greatestCommonFactor` just before that